# How to scroll at 20% of the html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I have the below code:

```
<a href="#home"></a>
```

I want go to the 20% of the page when I click this link.

Comment: Well.. a link is a good start I guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("body").height()*0.2},2000);
```

Comment: that's work! another people look like they don't understand the problem. Thank you.